# Writing mathematical expressions with chemical formulae

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

How can I write phrases like the ones shown below?
[image]

---

Edit: I tried using the `chemfig` package but I got this:

[image]

Comment: Hi & Welcome to TeX.SE! The [chemfig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemfig) package is probably what you're looking for. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemfig) are some related questions.

Comment: Regarding your Edit: Only posting a picture does not really help. We would need the full code to know where the problem lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your custom symbols using Ti*k*Z for example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\moleculeA}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5em, y=.5em, baseline]
        \foreach \x in {{{-1*cos(30)},1.5}, {0,0}, {{2*cos(30)},0}, {{4*cos(30)},0}, {{5*cos(30)},1.5}} {
            \begin{scope}[shift={(\x)}]
                \draw (30:1) -- (90:1) -- (150:1) -- (210:1) -- (270:1) -- (330:1) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\moleculeB}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5em, y=.5em, baseline]
        \foreach \x in {{{-1*cos(30)},1.5}, {0,0}, {{2*cos(30)},0}} {
            \begin{scope}[shift={(\x)}]
                \draw (30:1) -- (90:1) -- (150:1) -- (210:1) -- (270:1) -- (330:1) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        }
        \begin{scope}[shift={({4*cos(30)},0)}]
            \draw (210:1) -- (270:1) -- (330:1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\moleculeC}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5em, y=.5em, baseline]
        \foreach \x in {{{-1*cos(30)},1.5}, {0,0}, {{2*cos(30)},0}, {{4*cos(30)},0}} {
            \begin{scope}[shift={(\x)}]
                \draw (30:1) -- (90:1) -- (150:1) -- (210:1) -- (270:1) -- (330:1) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        }
        \begin{scope}[shift={({5*cos(30)},1.5)}]
            \draw (150:1) -- (210:1)
                  (270:1) -- (330:1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\moleculeD}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5em, y=.5em, baseline]
        \foreach \x in {{{-1*cos(30)},1.5}, {0,0}, {{2*cos(30)},0}, {{4*cos(30)},0}} {
            \begin{scope}[shift={(\x)}]
                \draw (30:1) -- (90:1) -- (150:1) -- (210:1) -- (270:1) -- (330:1) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        }
        \begin{scope}[shift={({5*cos(30)},1.5)}]
            \draw (90:1) -- (150:1) -- (210:1) 
                  (270:1) -- (330:1) -- (30:1);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\moleculeE}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5em, y=.5em, baseline]
        \foreach \x in {{{-1*cos(30)},1.5}, {0,0}, {{2*cos(30)},0}} {
            \begin{scope}[shift={(\x)}]
                \draw (30:1) -- (90:1) -- (150:1) -- (210:1) -- (270:1) -- (330:1) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\moleculeF}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.5em, y=.5em, baseline]
        \foreach \x in {{{-1*cos(30)},1.5}, {0,0}, {{2*cos(30)},0}, {{4*cos(30)},0}} {
            \begin{scope}[shift={(\x)}]
                \draw (30:1) -- (90:1) -- (150:1) -- (210:1) -- (270:1) -- (330:1) -- cycle;
            \end{scope}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
P\Big(\moleculeA\Big)
 & = wP\Big(\moleculeB\Big) + P\Big(\moleculeC\Big) + P\Big(\moleculeD\Big) \\
 & = (w + 1)P\Big(\moleculeE\Big) + P\Big(\moleculeF\Big) \\
 & = (w + 1)(w^2 + 5w + 5) + (2w^2 + 8w + 7) \\
 & = w^3 + 8w^2 + 18w + 12.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. It was executed without error.

Answer (score 4):

with `chemfig`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\setchemfig{atom sep=1em, angle increment=30}
\begin{document}
\[
    P\chemleft(\chemfig{*6(--*6(--*6(---*6(------)---)---)--*6(------)--)}\chemright)
\]

\begin{align*}
    &= wP\chemleft(\chemfig{*6(--*6(--(--[1])---)--*6(------)--)}\chemright)
    + P\chemleft(\chemfig{*6(--*6(--*6(---(-)-(-)--)---)--*6(------)--)}\chemright)
    + P\chemleft(\chemfig{*6(--*6(--*6(---(--[3])-(--[1])--)---)--*6(------)--)}\chemright) \\
    &= (w+1)P\chemleft(\chemfig{*6(--*6(-----)--*6(------)--)}\chemright)
    +
    P\chemleft(\chemfig{*6(--*6(--*6(------)---)--*6(------)--)}\chemright) \\
    &= (w + 1)(w^2 + 5w + 5) + (2w^2 + 8w + 7) = w^3 + 8w^2 + 18w + 12.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, but an error occurred as a result of executing this code, and the output was the same as in the photo.

Comment: You should not add things to your original question that alter it completely. By adding the image to your question, one now would assume that you used the package `chemfig` in the first place and it got you an error. But this is not the case, since you did not mention `chemfig` in your original question. You may want to ask a new question as to why your code does not work as expected using the `chemfig` package and leave this question as it was. I changed your question to make it clear that the picture is a later edit to your question.